# Convert str dates to MongoDB date objects via Pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mongodb

I am using this method to insert rows of a CSV file into MongoDB

```py
def insertData(self, path=None):
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    self.collection.insert_many(data, ordered=False)
```

One of the columns if `df` is a string date of the form: `YYYY/MM/DD` when I perform a `pd.to_datetiem` on the column, it changes it to a `datetime[64]` which MongoDB recognizes as a BigInt.

How to I push datetime objects from python to MongoDB in a way that Mongo recognizes them as actual dates...

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line:

```py
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Seems to do the trick, will keep the question open for any alternatives :)